# Как понимается else if в C?

Tags: c, if

До этого немного учил Python (там "или если" такого не было)
Сейчас учу C, читаю книгу и в примере написано **else if** - что это?

```c
...
if (c==...)
  state = OUT;
else if (state == OUT){
  state = IN;
...
```

UPD:

```c
...
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
  ++nc;
  if (c=='\n')
    ++nl;
  if(c==' ' || c== '\n' || c=='\t')
    state = OUT;
  else if(state==OUT){
    state = IN;
    ++nw;
  }
}
```

Comment: elif - это ничто иное, как сокращение else if.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

С одной стороны, вы можете смотреть на эту конструкцию, как на набор последовательно проверяемых условий:

```
if (cond1)        // выполняется cond1?
{
    code1;        // да -> выполняем code1
}
else if (cond2)   // нет? проверяем дальше: выполняется cond2?
{
    code2;        // да -> выполняем code2
}
else if (cond3)   // нет? проверяем дальше: выполняется cond3?
{
    code3;        // да -> выполняем code3
}
else
{
    code4;        // все проверки не прошли - выполняем code4
}
```

То есть это есть некий аналог `switch`.

С другой стороны, в этой конструкции используется то, что `else` относится к ближайшему `if`, а значит, `if` после `else` — просто содержимое else-клаузы (которую можно для ясности отделить фигурными скобками):

```
if (cond1)
{
    code1;
}
else
{
    if (cond2)
    {
        code2;
    }
    else
    {
        if (cond3)
        {
            code3;
        }
        else
        {
            code4;
        }
    }
}
```

Таким образом, мы остаёмся в пределах привычного `if` с двумя вариантами.
Хотя так обычно не пишут, чтобы не плодить уровни вложенности.

---

**Обновление:**

Давайте разберём актуальный код:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) { // считать следующий символ и проверить
                                 // не кончился ли stdin
  ++nc;                          // увеличить счётчик символов
  if (c=='\n')                   // если строка закончилась,
    ++nl;                        // увеличить счётчик строк
  if(c==' ' || c== '\n' || c=='\t') // если текущий символ -- пробел,
    state = OUT;                 // перейти в состояние "между словами"
  else if(state==OUT){           // иначе текущий символ не пробел, и
                                 // если мы были в состоянии "между словами"
    state = IN;                  // то перейти в состояние "в слове"
    ++nw;                        // и увеличить счётчик слов
  }
}
```

Судя по всему, это утилита `wc`?

Comment: Написал кусок целиком (в UPD), там можно было уместить в if и else

Comment: @ALPHA: Обновил ответ.

Comment: Да, это пример wc из K&R.

Comment: @avp: Миленький пример стейт-машины.

Comment: Большое спасибо, что так хорошо отвечаете на мои вопросы)
А что если просто удалить if(state==OUT)? Кусок else все равно будет переключать в ИН?

Comment: @ALPHA: Именно так.

Comment: то есть if(state==OUT) там не нужно?

Comment: @ALPHA: Нужно. Потому что без `if(state==OUT)` код переключал бы в `state = IN` и увеличивал счётчик слов на _каждой_ букве слова, а не только на _первой_. Насчёт `state` это бы не помешало, а вот счётчик слов не сработал бы.

Answer (score 4):

Так понятней?

```
if( c == 1 )
{
    state = OUT;
}
else
{
    if( state == OUT )
    {
        state = IN;
    }
}
```

Comment: не подумал про elif (в пайтоне), но elif используется есть там нужно дать выбор из 3х и больше вариантов, в другом случае хватает if и else
Да, так понятнее))
НО state или OUT или IN, если не OUT значит IN, зачем тогда еще раз его проверять в втором if? Если можно написать else state=IN;

Comment: Ну мало чего. Некоторые пишут код вида int a = 1; if (a != 1) { exit(1);}

Comment: @ALPHA: Нет, после присвоения `state = OUT;` в следующий `if( state == OUT )` потокй исполнения не заходит.